# How to get logs on why an IPA won't install on an iPad/iPhone

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, ipa

A Xamarin Forms app for iOS built using VS 2k19, with apparently everything (certs, app-ids, provisioning profile) done by the book will not install on the corresponding iPhone and iPad.

There is just a darkened icon, and a message ".... app cannot install. Please try again later." or something to that effect.

This previously worked with a wildcard profile, but I had to change this to a specific profile for App Domain Associations entitlement. I do believe I have the bundle id and everything correct. Still, despite various attempts , the app will not install.

I don't have the devices so I have to do this in a convoluted effort of trial and error. Is there some way of asking the testers to get some detailed logs on why iTunes will not install the app, or the app cannot launch?

Comment: As you want to consume `Domain Associations` on your app, have you enabled this capability on Apple Portal in the Identifiers section? If you want to collect the device's log 1. connect your iPhone/iPad to your Mac 2. Open XCode, go to window => devices and simulators 3. select your device and check the logs in view device logs or open console

Comment: @LandLu thanks but I am using macincloud, and the domain association is set. I figured out the problem. It's undocumented and you will be interested in the issue. Will write up shortly

Comment: you could finish this discussion by posting an appropriate answer. This will help other community members learn more about this section.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT See below.

Answer (score 0):

Add Your Device UDID and generate provisioning profile again by selecting all devices.

Comment: I did this already. And, thanks, but this does not really address my question.

Answer (score 0):

To get logs I installed iTools and used the Console Logs feature while the install was happening. This is because my device was only being used to install the ipa, while builds were using macincloud.

The actual issue was interesting. In the entitlement.plist I had app domain association and push notifications set. The same in app Dev center. However, if the app Dev center does not have push entitlement fully configured, with push cert, the entitlement is ignored and the lists fail to match. Removing push temporarily fixed the install. The error manifests in install logs as a signing verification failure.